# Identifying locations within polygon using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, point-in-polygon, vector-layer

I have a series of locations stored within a Vector layer and want to write a query to understand which of these locations fall within the polygons from another layer using the QGIS Python console.

So far I have got this code - however it returns all locations, some of them several times.

```py
canvas = qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas()
layer1 = canvas.layer(0) #layer 1 is the polygons
layer2 = canvas.layer(1) #layer 2 is the locations
featuresloc = layer2.getFeatures()

for feature in featuresloc:
    geomloc = feature.geometry()
    featurespol = layer2.getFeatures()
    for featurep in featurespol:
        if featurep.geometry().within(geomloc):
            attributes = feature.attributes()
            print attributes
```

Can anyone provide any pointers as to how I can correct this?

Answer (score 1):

You have to merge all geometries from your "another layer" to one geometry.

```py
geom = QgsGeometry(featuresloc.next().geometry()) # create empty geometry object for your polygons

for g in featuresloc: 
   geom = geom.combine(g.geometry()) # add each features to one big geometry
```

Then check within:

```py
for featurep in featurespol:
    if featurep.geometry().within(geom):
        attributes = feature.attributes()
        print attributes
```

I hope it will work.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm getting an error using this code - 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'combine'. When I try to add all the features in one big geometry is that just from the location layer or from both the location and the poly layer?

Comment: It's because geom was created as NoneType geometry instead of Polygon. I'm not sure how to create empty geometry, if you pass polygon like: `QgsGeometry.fromPolygon([[point,point,...]])` it will be Polygon type. You can get first feature from featuresloc layer, and pass its geometry to `fromPolygon()`

Comment: I've edited first line, try now.

Comment: I'm now getting this error: TypeError: QgsGeometry.fromPolygon(unknown-type): argument 1 has unexpected type 'QgsGeometry'

Comment: Without fromPolygon(): `geom = QgsGeometry(featuresloc.next().geometry())`